How to write multipe math equations inline on a single line in Sphinx
I want to write a simple line as below in my Sphinx reST document:

To write the line using :math: flag:
We know that :math:`A \to B \vdash A \to \forall x B`, provided that :math:`x` is not free in :math:`A`.

The appearance shown in browser after make html:

How can make it a one line without line break?
I want to tune the line with restructuredtext grammar to get the desired appearnce ,instead of tune the html or css code.
I have installed Furo as my default theme, try to write logic formula :
math formula
===================
p1:

We know that :math:`A \to B \vdash A \to \forall x B`, provided that :math:`x` is not free in :math:`A`.


p2:

.. raw:: html

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <title>MathJax example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" async
     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
   </script>
   <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
     tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   We know that `A \to B \vdash A \to \forall x B`, provided that `x` is not free in `A`.
   </body>
   </html>

The appearance:

If i delete the p2 part,all multipe math equations inline can't be on a single line shown in my browser:

How can fix it then?

I believe if you open developer tools of your browser, then styles are there for you to tune.

I want to tune the line with restructuredtext grammar to get the desired appearnce ,instead of tune the html or css code.

Can you write the plain text inside the :math:? That could avoid the line breaks. ReST itself wouldn't line break until you reach the maximum line length, but it's likely to add a line break after each :math: role... Do the roles get converted to images?

Your reStructuredText source line is the correct syntax for a paragraph with mixed text and inline math content. A conforming rendering would not introduce hard line breaks (but break the lines to fit into the given text width at the respective point in your document. There may be an error in the Sphinx math rendering extension or just not enough space (text width, e.g. if you view the content on a mobile in portrait mode).

One suspicious point in the sample output is the use of a monospaced font for the text parts: is the source line part of a "parsed-literal block"? Then, line breaks in the source are preserved (but there should still not be any additional line breaks according to the rST syntax).

Upgrade my sphinx to the latest version-8,inline math words do not have a break line.

I doubt the upgrade itself resolved this (as the generated HTML should be the same). Maybe the default theme alabaster was patched. Anyway people might not care much about the details.

Whether you like it or not, the result of make html is HTML and CSS so the rendering will be fully controlled by the rules.
Your snippet in reStructuredText is compiled to the following HTML elements,
<p>We know that <span class="math notranslate nohighlight">\(A \to B \vdash A \to \forall x B\)</span>, provided that <span class="math notranslate nohighlight">\(x\)</span> is not free in <span class="math notranslate nohighlight">\(A\)</span>.</p>

So, when I use the Furo theme to test, the preview looks like this,

You see something differently, probably because the theme you chose aligns elements another way.
